# Full Parse objects are not available to Underscore template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform, underscore.js-templating

I am building a web page to show recent donations by all users of a Parse based app. I am building this off of the example Todo application found here:https://parse.com/tutorials/todo-app-with-javascript. Here's the code in my main .js file(which mostly mirrors the tutorial todo.js other than the replaced class names and such):

```
//Donation Model
//--------------
 var Donation = Parse.Object.extend("Donation", {
    //instance methods
    //Default attributes
    defaults: {
    },

    //Ensure that each donation created has content
    initialize: function() {
    }
});


// This is the transient application state, not persisted on Parse
var AppState = Parse.Object.extend("AppState", {
    defaults: {
        filter: "all"
    }
});

//Donation Collection
//-------------------

var DonationList = Parse.Collection.extend({
    model: Donation

});

//Donation Item View
//-----------------

var DonationView = Parse.View.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    template: _.template($('#donation-template').html()),

    //The DOM events specific to donation
    events: {

    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});


//The Application
//---------------

var AdminView = Parse.View.extend({
    el: ".content",
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll', 'render');
        this.$el.html(_.template($('#admin-template').html()));

        ////create out collection of donations
        this.donations = new DonationList;

        //setup the Parse query
        var query = new Parse.Query(Donation);
        query.include("user");
        query.include("charity");
        query.include("business");
        this.donations.query = query;
        this.donations.bind('add', this.addOne);
        this.donations.bind('reset', this.addAll);
        this.donations.bind('all', this.render);

        this.donations.fetch({
            success: function(donations) {
                for(var i = 0; i < donations.length;i++) {
                    console.warn(donations.models[i]);
                }
            }
        });
        state.on("change", this.filter, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.delegateEvents();
    },
    filter: function() {
        this.addAll();
    },
    addOne: function(donation) {
        var view = new DonationView({model: donation});
        this.$("#donation-list").append(view.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function(collection, filter) {
        this.$('#donation-list').html("");
        this.donations.each(this.addOne);
    }
});


//The main view for the app
var AppView = Parse.View.extend({
    // Instead of generating a new element, bind to the existing skeleton of
    //the App already present in the HTML.
    el: $("#adminapp"),

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        new AdminView();
    }
});

var state = new AppState;
new AppView;
```

When the models are fetched from Parse in

```
this.donations.fetch({
            success: function(donations) {
                for(var i = 0; i < donations.length;i++) {
                    console.warn(donations.models[i]);
                }
            }
        });
```

I have all of the pointer relations on Donation in full, such as the user and all of their properties and the charity and all of its properties etc. However, I'm interested in displaying the username of the user who made a donation in an underscore template, but at that point the user object on donation no longer has a username property. It's as if some properties are being removed between the time the query returns and when the template is provided with the new collection of donations. Here's the underscore template:

```
<script type="text/template"  id="donation-template">
    <td><%= donationAmount %></td>
    <td><%= charity %></td>
    <td><%= user  %></td>
    <td><%= business  %></td>
    <td><%= createdAt  %></td>
</script>
```

donationAmount and createdAt are displayed as expected, but charity, user, and business are just displayed as [Object object], and I can't access any of their properties with dot notation. How can I ensure that the properties I need on all of these pointer relations are available for consumption by the underscore view?

Comment: Read the Parse JS SDK Docs on how to populate pointers and relationships. They aren't populated by default

Comment: Isn't include supposed to accomplish this? I'm able to see all of the object properties if I log them in the success block of the query, but then they seem to be unavailable after that.

Answer (score 0):

setup the UserList as a model collection

```
return Parse.Collection.extend({
        model: User
});
```

do the 'relation' query and set local model/var

```
    this.collection = new UserList();
    this.model = this.options.model;  

    var relation = this.model.relation("users");
    this.collection.query = relation.query();       
    var user = this.model.id;
    var username = this.model.get("name");
    this.collection.fetch();
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure where you're suggesting I place this code. Could you elaborate on that a bit? Thanks for the help

Comment: well. the sample code is from backbone/marionette/ project accessing parse.Users in a relational query ( query access via relation or pointer to User) . If you are using an MVC framework with collections , i thought it may provide some idea.